# Deploy Servlet to Tomcat hosting

Tags: facebook, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I create Facebook JSP Application. I use **Restful Java Client** Web Services. And created .java file. in this file have Servlet. but can not deploy it into the hosting. I deployed follow

```
WEB-INF  
    -classes  
       -facebook     
               -socialnetworkingservice 
                      -facebookresponse  
                                  ......and many classes     
        -META-INF  
        -org  
          -my  
               -facebook  
                   -client  
                        FacebookClient$FacebookCallbackServlet.class  
                        FacebookClient$FacebookLoginServlet.class      
                        FacebookClient.class

    -lib
          ..lib files
    -web.xml
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FacebookClient$FacebookLoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.my.facebook.client.FacebookClient$FacebookLoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FacebookClient$FacebookCallbackServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.my.facebook.client.FacebookClient$FacebookCallbackServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacebookClient$FacebookLoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/FacebookLoginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacebookClient$FacebookCallbackServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/FacebookCallbackServlet/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

META-INf ( I think it is not important)

I compile localhost and have (MyFbFriend.war)

and I get this error

"Not Found

The requested URL /FacebookLoginServlet was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: Which tomcat version you are using ?

Comment: Can you check the tomcat logs such as stdout.log, localhost.log, catalina.log ?  what is says about the issue ?

Comment: The way you structured your servlet classes is strange. Put them each in their own classes instead of making them static nested classes and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
http://localhost:8080/MyFbFriend/FacebookLoginServlet/
```

The name of the War gives the Context of the App